# Loading a PNG file to openGL ES

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, png

Im trying to set a certain texture to an object on `openGL ES` this is how i load it:

```
- (GLuint)setupTexture:(NSString *)fileName {
    // 1
    CGImageRef spriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].CGImage;
    if (!spriteImage) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load image %@", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);


    GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width*height*4, sizeof(GLubyte));


    CGContextRef spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width*4,
                                                       CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), spriteImage);

    CGContextRelease(spriteContext);
...
}
```

Now, when i'm using this `tile_floor.png` file:

[image]

the image is loaded and drawn on screen.

but when i use this `wood.png` file:

[image]

all i get is a black object.

Why is it different? is there any importance to the file dimensions (width or height)? i did not 'hard code' any dimensions or parameters, so that all images can be loaded.

It's important to say i don't get any errors in the console, and the program is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use NPOT (non-power of two) image in many OpenGL ES implementations (all iOS devices support the extension GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot) you have to use the right edge mode:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

This will make the texture clamp to the edges of the texture coordinates 0, 1 range. Your wood texture looks like it does not repeat anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer nikolai, i tried to change the code to your offer, but i get black object again. any idea why?

Comment: @Itzik984 Do you use any funny mipmap filter (other than nearest or linear)?

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know the reason why this fails for you. It definitely works for me (and many others).

Comment: Nikolai, i added the lines you gave to the already in use lines as followed:
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
And it did work. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK, seems to have been a funny min filter setting.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i got this. openGL ES requires power of 2 image size (both width and height).
Resized the photo and it worked.

Comment: This should have been a comment and not a new answer.